# Performance of Qt/ODBC/MS-SQL and Sybase

Tags: qt, sybase, sql-server-express

I have here some application which can run with MS SQL Sqlexpress or with Sybase. The database scheme is the same (ignoring differences like "text" on Sybase and "varchar(max)" on MS-SQL).

For historical reasons Sybase is implemented with its native interface and MS-SQL uses Qt and its ODBC-Interface.

Both use almost the same queries (which are generated from an internal query-language) – there are very small differences caused by the SQL dialect. Both have the same set of indexes, both hold the same data. And on both I did "UPDATE STATISTICS".

Now when I start my test application on the same box where the database runs, MS-SQL need about twice the time of Sybase. I can live with that, this is not the main problem.

But when I start the application on a different box than the database server, MS-SQL really slows down. The difference is about factor 10 which causes headaches :-(

Are there any tips, any trick, hidden features for a speed up?

There is one main difference in the queries:

Sybase:

```
SELECT node.* FROM node, other WHERE node.id = other.node_id GROUP BY node.id
```

MS-SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT node.* FROM node, other WHERE node.id = other.node_id
```

Well, maybe I should generate it with a GROUP BY clause and a full field list, but would that cause a big difference?

The main problem I see is the gigantic slowdown when client and server are running on different computers and this seems to be caused by a very different communication between client and server, which sure will not be faster with different queries.

So, any ideas? Comments?

Comment: I'm not a big SQL guy, but I know that DISTINCT is an expensive operation, and should be avoided when possible.  But, as you've already stated, the slow down you are experiencing won't likely be fixed by changing the query, as it's related to network/communications latency.

Comment: Michael, I did not mention the times, just the factor. Client & DB-Server on the same machine takes about 1min 45sec. Client on different machine takes about 16min. So even if I optimize the querys to zerotime, there are still 14 minutes missing.

Answer (score 0):

Using QSqlQuery::setForwardOnly(true) seems to solve my problem. This is a real booster.